# Which datastructure to send to d3.js script?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, data-structures, d3.js

So I'm going to need to iterate through some info I'm pulling from my database and render it dynamically in a D3 chart.  The two pieces of info I need are a answer's title and its number of votes.  I'm currently doing it like this:

```
  def show
    @poll = Poll.find(params[:id])
    # Mappning answer titles with their votes 
    gon.poll = @poll.questions[0].answers.map{|answer| [answer.title, answer.votes]}
```

Giving this result:

```
[["Probably not", 4],
 ["But you're saying there's a chance", 10],
 ["I just added this...", 7]]
```

**And passing it to this script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var w = 500;
  var h = 420;
  var barPadding = 1;
  // var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
  //                 11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];
  var dataset [gon.poll];

  // function drawSurvey(){
    var svg = d3.select('div.graph')
                .append("svg") 
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height",h);
                // .attr("class", "bar")
                // });

    svg.selectAll("rect")
       .data(dataset)
       // Each data point entered into enter() for processing
       .enter()
       .append("rect")
       .attr("x", function(d, i) {
          return i * (w / dataset.length);  //Bar width of 20 plus 1 for padding
      // tying of each bar as a function to length of set, never runs off screen
       })
       .attr("y", function(d){
          return h-d
       })
       // Less bars == more width
       .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
       .attr("height", function(d){
        return d
       })
       .attr("fill", "teal");

  // }

});
```

I'm wondering if this is the most efficient way to work with the data though?  I'll want each bar to have the height of its votes, with its 'title' on the x-axis.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure I would use would be an array of objects:

```
[{title: "Probably not", votes: 4},
{title: "But you're saying there's a chance", votes: 10},
{title: "I just added this...", votes: 7}]
```

Then, further down in the code:

```
.attr("y", function(d) {return d.votes;})
```

and

```
.attr("height", function(d) {return d.votes;})
```

Then for the title you can use `d.title` to access the right value.

Comment: my god i wish I had formatted it this way from the start, would've saved a lot of time.  thanks!